# Go through a CSV line by line and see if there is a string

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm running the following command:

```
Import-Csv .\list.csv -Encoding UTF8 -Header "Users"
```

which is a list basically with names, users and a attribute

```
Users
-----
Bob;User1;T
Max;User2;
Jordon:User3;T
Angel;User4;T
```

As you can see there are 3 users with a `;T`. I should be able to able to search through that line (string) and if I find that `;T` I'll do something. If I don't find that `;T` I'll do something else.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: What is reasoning behind *not* using `-Delimiter ";" -Header Name,User,Attribute` and then `if($_.Attribute -ne "T"){ do-somethingelse }`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Just make that the answer to this one. Or at least an answer

Comment: @Matt you're right, done!

Answer (score 2):

Supply a `Header` field per column, otherwise you're not really getting any value from using `Import-Csv`. You can also specify a custom delimiter, in your example, a semicolon (`;`):

```
foreach($Row in Import-Csv .\list.csv -Encoding UTF8 -Header Name,User,Attribute -Delimiter ";") {
    if($Row.Attribute -eq 'T'){
        Do-Something -User $Row.User
    } else {
        Do-SomethingElse -Name $Row.Name
    }
}
```

If the statements you want to execute are very concise, you could also use a switch:

```
foreach($Row in Import-Csv .\list.csv -Encoding UTF8 -Header Name,User,Attribute -Delimiter ";") {
    switch($Row.Attribute){
        'T'     { Do-Something -User $Row.User }
        default { Do-SomethingElse -Name $Row.Name }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a Select-String instead like this:

```
Select-String .\list.csv -Encoding UTF8 -Pattern '^([^;]+);([^;]+)(?=;T$)' | % {
  $name = $_.matches.Groups[1].value
  $login = $_.matches.Groups[2].value
  #do stuff
}
```

You can just repeat the above code for every other type you want to process by just adjusting the regex pattern.